# Crystal Reports - suppressing records before a specific date but keep null records

Tags: mysql, date, crystal-reports

I have a report that includes a date field. I want to suppress records that are before a specific date but want to keep records that don't have a date in the date field. So for example:

'First Name|Last Name|Date'
'John|Doe|1/1/2008'
'Sally|Smith| '
'Barry|Allen|1/1/2017'

I would want to keep anything after say 1/1/2010 OR blank date and suppress anything before 1/1/2010, so returning the Sally and Barry records. Appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a formula to suppress the section your rowdata prints within.

The formula would look like this:

```
NOT ISNULL({YourTable.Date}) or {YourTable.Date} >= "1/1/2010";
```

This formula will evaluate to either a True or False that will determine if the section is suppressed or not.